# How to pass a local file name to css-validator.jar?

Tags: command-line

I'm trying to open a file from the filesystem with css-validator.jar.  I tried:

`java -jar css-validator.jar C:\filename` and
`java -jar css-validator.jar file:\\\filename`

but neither worked.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'll say that this question could have been worded in a way making it much easier to read, but it certainly isn't too broad if you actually take the time to read it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Figured it out on my own: command used in directory of jar is like this:

```
java -jar css-validator.jar -output gnu file:///"Directory of file"\"name of css file".css
```

You can then add > or >> and a text type file extension (.txt, .html, .xml, .doc[but not .docx]) to output to file.  the gnu can also be text, xml, or a couple other formats.